# java Junit testing

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

есть проект простенький рест сервис: [битбакет](https://bitbucket.org/ilyach12/department-server/src)

Весь код должен быть покрыт тестами Junit. Я этого никогда раньше не делал, но вот написал небольшой тест для одного из методов контроллера(в сурс коде назван не правильно класс теста). Подскажите, что с ним не так, как можно улучшить, и почему выдаёт nullPointerExeption при его запуске?

Вот код теста, собсна. (Что он тестирует, думаю, будет удобнее глянуть в репозитории):

```
public class DepartmentControllerTest {

private final List<Department> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Before
public void initDepartment(){

    Department department = new Department();
    department.setId(2L);
    department.setDepartmentName("Java");
    department.setEmployeesInThisDepartment(null);

    list.add(department);
}

@Test
public void testList() throws Exception {
    DepartmentService departmentService = new DepartmentService();
    when(departmentService.getAll()).thenReturn(list);
    DepartmentController  departmentController = new DepartmentController();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(departmentController, "departmentService", departmentService);
    ExtendedModelMap uiModel = new ExtendedModelMap();
    uiModel.addAttribute("departments", departmentController.getAllDepartments());
    Department department = (Department) uiModel.get("departments");
    assertEquals(1, department.getEmployeesInThisDepartment().size());
}
```

> > java.lang.NullPointerException
> >         at com.service.DepartmentService.getAll(DepartmentService.java:24)
> >         at dao.DepartmentDaoTest.testList(DepartmentDaoTest.java:37)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
> >         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> >         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
> >         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> >         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
> >         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
> >         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> >         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> >         at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
> >         at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
> >         at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
> >         at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
> >         at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >         at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: NPE летит собственно на что?

Comment: Стактрейсы добавь, непонятно же ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На DAO слой тесты не пишутся. Можно использовать моки или встроенные БД, но это не для начинающих.

И смотри, ты только создал new DepartmentService(), соответственно, он совершенно пустой и тут же хочешь у него получить getAll

Comment: *"На DAO слой тесты не пишутся"* -- как ж его тогда проверять? :)

Comment: выше написано - моки или встроенные БД